# Typescript building URL with optional arguments

Tags: javascript, url, typescript, httprequest

I'm trying to build a URL to fetch data from a REST service, a valid url should look like this

`http://SITENAME/api/get_posts/?count=5&page=1&post_type=gallery`

and I have arguments like **count**, **page**, **post_type** and more..
these are optional arguments and one or all could be null
I tried the following code

```
var query = 'http://localhost/wptest/api/get_posts/?';
fetchData(countIn: int, pageIn: int, typeIn: string, query: string) {

    if (this.countIn)   //if count not null, add count parameter.
        query = `${query}&count=${this.countIn}`;
    if (this.pageIn)  
        query = `${query}&page=${this.pageIn}`;
    if (this.typeIn)  
        query = `${query}&post_type=${this.typeIn}`;

    return this.http.get(query).map(res => res.json());
}
```

this ugly code is returning an invalid URL, when I go to chrome debugger => network tab I find:

[image]

however I don't get an exception, because somehow the url get fixed and send a new request with the valid url:

[image]

the problem is with the difference between `?count=5&page=1` and `?&count=5&page=1`

this causing the tab spinner to be stuck and never ends.

[image]

**Q: what improvements can be done to the code in order to get a valid URL?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping the general structure of your current code, you could add a variable that gets set with the '&' after the first instance of it being used.

```
fetchData(countIn: int, pageIn: int, typeIn: string, query: string) {
    var prepend = '';
    if (this.countIn)  { 
        query = `${query}` + prepend + `count=${this.countIn}`;
        prepend = '&';
    }
    if (this.pageIn)  {
        query = `${query}` + prepend + `page=${this.pageIn}`;
        prepend = '&';
    }
    if (this.typeIn)  {
        query =  `${query}` + prepend + `post_type=${this.typeIn}`;
        prepend = '&';
    }

    return this.http.get(query).map(res => res.json());
}
```

There are other ways to achieve what you're trying to accomplish, but this is one way to do it.

Comment: nice way of doing it. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var params = [], // your params here
    self = this;
[["count", "countIn"], ["page", "pageIn"], ["post_type", "postIn"]]
  .forEach(function(param) { 
     if(self[param[1]]) params.push(param[0] + "=" + self[param[1]]); 
  });
var query = `${query}` + params.join("&");
```

Comment: did you notice `${query}&` the char `&` before the first argument is making the whole problem

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I'm hurry and write it by scratch without testing.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
var query = 'http://localhost/wptest/api/get_posts/?';
var counter = 0;
fetchData(countIn: int, pageIn: int, typeIn: string, query: string) {

if (this.countIn && counter = 0){  //if count not null, add count parameter.
    query = `${query}count=${this.countIn}`;
counter++;
}
elseif(this.countIn){  //if count not null, add count parameter.
    query = `${query}&count=${this.countIn}`;
} 

if (this.pageIn && counter = 0){  //if count not null, add count parameter.
    query = `${query}count=${this.pageIn}`;
counter++;
}
elseif(this.pageIn){  //if count not null, add count parameter.
    query = `${query}&count=${this.pageIn}`;
} 

if (this.typeIn && counter = 0){  //if count not null, add count parameter.
    query = `${query}count=${this.typeIn}`;
counter++;
}
elseif(this.typeIn){  //if count not null, add count parameter.
    query = `${query}&count=${this.typeIn}`;
} 



return this.http.get(query).map(res => res.json());
}

    query = `${query}&post_type=${this.typeIn}`;
```

this is a workaround I believe.

Comment: what if `count` is null, and my first argument is `page` ?